# Which Crops/Other Plants Could be Grown in a "Tropical Mediterranean" Climate?

Tags: climate, flora, agriculture, farming

In my book series, the region around the capital city of one of my planets has a very odd climate: while it has the year-round warm-to-hot weather of a tropical climate, it also has an exaggerated version of Mediterranean rainfall patterns: bone-dry summers and a winter monsoon season. I input the area's climate into a koppen climate calculator I found on the internet and it came out as Csa (hot-summer Mediterranean) but just barely: [image: Climate Data For the City of Astras] Since I could find no real easy analogue for this type of climate on Earth,what kinds of crops would people be able to grow in this type of area? What kinds of ornamental plants could one grow in the city itself?

Note: the planet's culture and technology is based on an amalgamation of Ancient Greece, Ancient Rome, and Byzantium so keep that in mind in regards to agricultural technology.

Comment: I was baffled too, then I realised my mistake - the units! I'd really appreciate it if you could post another screenshot of that table not in American. 64F is 17 degrees C. 78f is 25 degrees C.

Comment: this really depends on how well drained the land is, how advanced agricultural technology is, and the quality of the soil, also how much labor is available. long dry summers however will favor cereals as a staple.

Comment: agree with @John.  If you can catch the rain in a reservoir and use it for irrigation you have the Imperial Valley and you can grow lots of things.

Comment: @Ash converted the table from Freedom Units to Metric.

Comment: (1) What does the word "winter" mean in the context of a "tropical" climate? (2) How is this different from India? (3) Byzantium was a small and unimportant city on the shore of the Bosporus; you probably mean Constantinople. (Pet peeve: the name "Byzantine" empire was invented by a German historian long after that empire had fallen. While that empire was extant, its inhabitants called themselves Romans, the emperor called himself Roman emperor, both its friends and its *enemies* called it the Roman empire, and the capital was called Constantinople.)

Comment: @AlexP 1) "Winter" refers to the coolest set of months (the middle of the year since this is in its planet's southern hemisphere) 2) India's wet and dry seasons are at the opposite time of year. The monsoon arrives in the summer and the winters are dry, this is the other way around. 3) When I say "Byzantium", I am referring to the Eastern Roman Empire from 476-1453 CE, this is semantics.

Comment: I apologize Weasle, but -1. Every coastal community along the Mediterranean can be referenced and would give you a perfectly sound list of commodities. I think you're being too specific. If you want some specificity, focus on the North African coastal areas. I don't see why the answer to this isn't a trivial Google search.

Comment: *"India's wet and dry seasons are at the opposite time of year":* India is a big place. Take a look at the [climate of Chennai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chennai#Climate) (a very large city, formerly known as Madras). Note the correlation between precipitation and average temperature: the hottest months are dry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Lots will grow in that climate

Converting from "Freedom Units" to SI: You have average temperature min/max of 17 degrees Celsius in winter, 25 degrees Celsius in summer. That sounds familiar. It's the next city over from me:

After some googling, if we plot your average along the graph, it's about the middle of the average daytime max and average nightime min:

[image]

Your rainfall is about twice Perth's, but fits the same general shape of a winter peak. "14 inches" is 350mm of rain. So your land is equivalent to a plot of farmland near Perth which is irrigated over what rains by a factor of two.

[image]

[A lot of things can grow in this climate](https://www.bibralakesoils.com.au/build-a-vegetable-garden/). Sorting by month of planting:

- January: beetroot, capsicum, celery, carrots, kale, eggplant
- February: leeks, lettuce, melons, radish
- March: beans (runner), broccoli, chillies, cauliflowers
- April: broad beans, onions, spring onions
- May: Brussels sprouts, parsnips, peas
- June: potatoes, silver beets, spinach
- July: swede, turnips, chives
- August: asparagus, kohl rabi, Jerusalem artichoke
- September: beans (dwarf), zucchini, melons
- October: squash, peas, turnips
- November: tomatoes, spring onions, beans (snake)
- December: zucchini, radish, carrots

The [most exported crops](https://www.agriculture.gov.au/abares/research-topics/agricultural-outlook/australian-crop-report/western-australia) from that region are Wheat, Barley, Canola, and Lupins.